# How to get Row count for sql select query taht not return any record and add that in ArraryList

Tags: java, jdbc

I have one problem that in my java programme when i select some record from database,i need records which are not retrun by sql query from database.
suppose i have 5 record in my table and i give 8 record in where condition in my java programme so i need 3 record in ArrayList for that programme did not retrun any values..

My sample programme is as below:-

```
import java.sql.*;
```

import java.util.ArrayList;
public class database {

```
   static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";  
   static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl";


   static final String USER = "asiftest";
   static final String PASS = "asif";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Connection conn = null;
   Statement stmt = null;
   try{

      Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");



      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
      ArrayList ar =new  ArrayList();

      System.out.println("Creating statement...");
      stmt = conn.createStatement();
      String sql;
      sql = "SELECT contractno FROM temp_survival where contractno in ('77777','11111','22222','33333','44444','55555','66666','77777','363636','25252')";
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);


      while(rs.next()){


         String first = rs.getString("contractno");

         System.out.print("contractno: " + first);

      }

      rs.close();
      stmt.close();
      conn.close();
   }catch(SQLException se){

      se.printStackTrace();
   }catch(Exception e){

      e.printStackTrace();
   }finally{

      try{
         if(stmt!=null)
            stmt.close();
      }catch(SQLException se2){
      }
      try{
         if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         se.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

}
}
```

For the above programme i am getting values for '77777','11111','22222','33333','44444','55555','66666','77777' but for next 2 records '363636','25252' i am are not getting values because that is not available in database table so i need to add them in arraylist in above proramme. Please help me

Comment: Can you explaine more i can't understand waht do you expect?

Comment: @Abdelhak He want to return a consistent result set, but someone has deleted some records. How to get records that was deleted? Am I right?

Comment: Yes Roman..I want that records that are not available in result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make a List for input contact numbers (which you are passing in where clause)
2. Make a List of contact numbers which you are getting in the query results
3. Use `CollectionUtils.substract(list1, list2)`